# Using 'self' in Swift 2, Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nstimer, xcode7

I am making a timer just under the class opening braces (before viewDidLoad) to use as a variable for the entire class. However, when I try to set the timer's target to 'self' I get the error:

```
Argument type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'
```

Here is the code for the timer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

     var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `timer` just under the class opening braces (before viewDidLoad) this way:

```
var timer: NSTimer?
```

Now in your `viewDidLoad` method add this code:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And you can access it anywhere into your class.

Comment: Why initialise the timer only to throw that instance away later?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your question.

Comment: You should use `var timer: NSTimer?` rather than creating one before you set it.